# Change thing in the middle of the string notepad++

Tags: hyperlink, notepad++

My file contains things like this:

```
http://example.com/main.do?y=yeay
http://example.com/main.do?y=hahahehe
http://example.com/main.do?d=wow
http://example.com/blah/blah/product.do?p=49302
```

etc...

I want to change them all like following.

```
http://example.com/main.do@y=yeay.html
http://example.com/main.do@y=hahahehe.html
http://example.com/main.do@d=wow.html
http://example.com/blah/blah/product.do@p=49302.html
```

These are the links in a html/do/asp files.
How can I change them? Thanks.
I can also use other programs not noteoad++ and i have both macOS and WIndows
THanks

Comment: There are also other files here so if i replace ? with @ then they gets broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `https?\S+?\.do\K\?(\S+)`
- Replace with: `@$1.html`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
https?      # http OR https
\S+?        # 1 or more non spaces, not greedy
\.          # a dot
do          # literally "do"
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\?          # question mark
(\S+)       # group 1, 1 or more non spaces
```

**Replacement:**

```
@           # literally
$1          # content of group 1
.html       # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]